# Set minimum width of chrome app

Tags: javascript, properties, google-chrome-app

I am trying to set the minimum width of a chrome app and I looked at some [chrome documention](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-Bounds) and I implemented it into my chrome app like this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
     chrome.app.window.create(
        'index.html',
        {
            id: 'mainWindow',
            bounds: {
                width: 800, 
                height: 600,
                minWidth: 600
            }
        }
    );
});
```

However I got the error:

> Error
>   Error in event handler for app.runtime.onLaunched: Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property 'bounds.minWidth': Unexpected property.

From my knowledge, this means that the property doesn't exist but this can't be the case as it's in the documentation. Maybe I implemented it wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Their documentation says that property has only been used "Since Chrome 35."  Are you developing against an older version of Chrome?

Comment: Also, it looks like bounds requires you to have two properties that you are not implementing: top and bottom.  That may be contributing to the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it's `innerBounds` I needed to use! Here is my code now:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
    chrome.app.window.create(
     'index.html',
{
      id: 'mainWindow',
      bounds: {width: 800, height: 600},
      innerBounds: { minWidth: 800}
    }
  );
});
```